# Remote EJB invocation from Quartz Job on WildFly fails after module restart

Tags: ejb, wildfly, quartz

I have a simple application with a Quartz scheduler started from a servlet listener. The code is available at https://github.com/ike3/quartz-and-ejb

The only interesting part is that the job calls a remote EJB:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
PpaJobRemote remote = (PpaJobRemote) initialContext.lookup(beanName);
remote.process();
```

The code is packaged as EAR containing EJB-JAR and WAR and then deployed on the WildFly 18 application server. To be sure: there are no duplicated interfaces in EAR/lib and WEB-INF/lib.

Everything works fine until the module is restarted. Then suddenly the lookup fails with an exception:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination 
for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "fz44-test-jobs-ear/fz44-test-jobs-ejb/SendMailMessageJob", 
view is interface ru.lanit.fz44.ejb.job.PpaJobRemote, affinity is None
```

The problem occurs only from a Quartz Job. I have servlet calling the same job in the same WAR - it works fine after such restart. So I think there is some weird bug between Quartz thread pool and Widlfly classloaders.

If I restart the whole server (not the single module) the error is gone. The problem is worse that deploy scripts in the CI server use jboss CLI effectively restarting the module now and then.

Can anyone suggest any workarounds of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I figured it out. The problem is that I didn't shutdown the scheduler. Aparently Quartz reuses the same scheduler even after the app is restarted.

Adding this to the servlet listener fixed the issue.

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    try {
        if (sched.isStarted()) {
             sched.shutdown();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

One more example that all the resources must be closed after use and forgetting to do so can lead to strange issues.